# css transform translate top right

Tags: css, transform

When using transform translate, how can I move something to the top right most point of the window?

I can move things around fine using pixel values, but i cannot know what the value is of the top right corner of the page.

```
transform: translate(10000px, -5000px);-
```

Is what I am using now

Comment: Why do you need to use transform for this?

Comment: We need to see the code part of this, which you are going to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS fixed position.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: I want to animate from one position to the top right corner

Comment: Can you create a demo via Codepen/JsFiddle?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest use `position:absolute` for positioning your div, `relative to body`.

and then use the `position top:0, right:0, left: 100%` whichever suits.

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nKtC6/1482/